# Remote shutdown command not working for Windows Embedded computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, shutdown, windows-embedded-7

I am trying to Remotely shutdown a computer with windows embedded from windows 7 computer. Is not working with following command.

```
shutdown /s /f /m \\192.168.100.2 /t 5 /d u:0:0 /c "The Computer is shutting down"
```

I am getting access denied error message. 
Both computers are connected with the same router. Users with same name and password are being used on both computers. Both are admin users.

Comment: Check this [article](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/remote-shutdown-command/). And try the `shutdown /i`. Check if the other pc is discoverable in the network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up shutting down remote computer using the my own written program. 
See link for the details. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396